# BIND DNS works but BIND views do not work at all

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Good morning, in my company we are planning to implement BIND DNS for its views. So I set up a small test environment in VMware workstation (with no dhcp network) to play with views. I have 3 CentOS8 boxes one of which has BIND installed. The DNS works fine but not the views set up. Basically the centos dns clients can resolve anything as if views were not implemented. I am expecting that one client in one domain cannot resolve the other domain and viceversa. I have followed this video I have followed this video youtube.com/watch?v=AXsM18yyDQE  . Here below the config files involved, everything is setup as in the video but something is not right and I can't see what it is.

named.conf

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";

acl mezam {
    192.168.161.0/24;
    localhost;
};
acl silverz {
    192.168.162.0/24;
};
```

named.conf.options

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { any; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
    directory   "/var/named";

    dnssec-validation auto;
    allow-query { "any";};
    allow-recursion { "any";};
};
```

named.conf.local

```
view "mezam"
{
  match-clients { mezam; };

  zone "mezam.org." IN {
   type master;
   file "mezam.org.internal.zone";
  };
  zone "." IN {
   type hint;
   file "/var/named/named.ca";
  };
};

view "silverz"
{
  match-clients { silverz; };

  zone "silverz.org." IN {
   type master;
   file "silverz.org.internal.zone";
  };
};
```

and the zones:

```
$ORIGIN mezam.org.
$TTL    3M
@   IN  SOA ns1.mezam.org.  hostmaster.mezam.org.   2020042402  3M 3M 3M 3M
    IN  NS  ns1.mezam.org.
    IN  A   192.168.161.5
ns1 IN  A   192.168.161.5
centos8 IN  A   192.168.161.10
```

-

```
$ORIGIN silverz.org.
$TTL    3M
@   IN  SOA ns1.silverz.org.    hostmaster.silverz.org. 2020042502  3M 3M 3M 3M
    IN  NS  ns1.silverz.org.
    IN  A   192.168.161.5
ns1 IN  A   192.168.161.5
centos8x    IN  A   192.168.162.10
```

I rebooted the bind server and no resolution has been possible until I added recursion yes in the named.conf.options file. Now find below a dig output from a dns client in the 162 network towards mezam.org domain which should be refused but it is instead accepted:

```
[root@centos8x ~]# dig mezam.org

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el8 <<>> mezam.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51598
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 3e631d936b78fff089f3f8f45ea6b43109ba002df1beb326 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mezam.org.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mezam.org.      180 IN  A   192.168.161.5

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mezam.org.      180 IN  NS  ns1.mezam.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.mezam.org.      180 IN  A   192.168.161.5

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.161.5#53(192.168.161.5)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 27 12:30:09 CEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 116
```

Comment: What happens? Can you show `dig` output that is representative of the problems? (And anything in the logs?)

Comment: Considering that the question appears to fall in the "What am I missing?" category, I really do think that it would be better to show what happens as-is rather than sharing your analysis of what happened.

Comment: I've added a dig output to the question context

Comment: Thank you. If that is from a client in the `192.168.162.0/24` network, and it sends the query to `192.168.161.5` (the address of the nameserver, in the other network) and gets the wrong view (authoritative answer and everything), then for me that raises the question of what the connectivity between `192.168.162.0/24` and `192.168.161.0/24` is like? There's no NAT, is there?

Comment: If unsure, maybe either enable the query log or run tcpdump on the nameserver machine to confirm what the source address is for queries coming in from the other network. If the source address is that of the router's interface in the `192.168.161.0/24` network, then that would indicate that it's doing NAT between these networks (which would of course break this kind of address matching).

Comment: yes it is NATted as that is the network config of the VMware Workstation. I didn't think of that actually... many thanks indeed! I have to move the testlab somewhere else

Comment: I'll try to summarize the findings as an answer. Comments are not eligible to be answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in the question, a client in the `192.168.162.0/24` network, sends a query to `192.168.161.5` (the address of the nameserver, in the other network) and gets the wrong view (indicated as authoritative answer).

This raises the question of what the connectivity between the `192.168.162.0/24` network and the `192.168.161.0/24` network is like? Is there NAT?

To confirm this, enable the query log or run `tcpdump` on the nameserver machine to confirm what the source address is for queries coming in from the other network.
If the source address is that of the router's interface in the `192.168.161.0/24` network, then that would indicate that it's doing NAT between these networks (which would of course break this kind of address matching).

Based on comments, it appears that the hosts used for testing were virtual machines in an environment where their interconnection was NAT-based.